# Spark program to read XML and parse it using databricks spark_xml jar

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am trying to load an xml file and parse it using databricks spark_xml.

```
def loadXMLData(sqlContext: SQLContext) = {
var df : DataFrame = null
var newDf : DataFrame = null
import sqlContext.implicits._
df =sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","book").load("books_new.xml")
val newRdd: RDD[Row] = df.rdd
//printing each Row
newRdd.collect().foreach(a=>println(a))
df.printSchema()
df.registerTempTable("book")
sqlContext.sql("""select * from book """).show()

}
```

While iterating through Row i have a column email and I want to find out the id which doesnot have @ and update them as null before loading it into hive.
Also after registering as temp table I want to load the data in hive for which I added :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.5.0"
```

but it says cannot resolve symbol hive when I give :

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

how to go about this

Comment: Appreciate help in this regard

Comment: what cannot resolve hive? eclipse? the spark-submit?  what did you run with sbt?

Comment: Hive issue is fixed now but when trying to create a jar and when I do spark submit command in hortonworks vm; it say Class notFound exception : failed to load spark-xml

Comment: how did you build the jar? how does your sbt build file look like?